# Make an input log form per record in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Good morning,

I am kind of puzzled on how i will be able to make a log file with ruby on rails. I was able to do this in php pretty easy. but now i am learning Ruby On Rails

My Setup:

```
CentOS 6.5
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.0
Postgres 9.3
```

what i want to do is have a Text Area on a form that is disabled. but gets the data from the database. saved into a `:text` field in the database.

then i want a string field on the form that will add a timestamp to the New Notes and add it to the info in the disabled field.

I don't need or want a extra column for the update text field every time this form is loaded i want that field to be blank.

something like the following example:

[image]

This is an example of what i have

VIEW:

```
<%= form_for(@lead) do |f| %>
    <% if @lead.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@lead.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this lead from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @lead.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>

          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div align="center" class="edit_view" id="<%= @lead.id %>">
<table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><%= f.label :notes %></th>
    <th scope="col"><%= f.text_area :notes %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= f.label :update %></th>
    <th scope="row"><%= f.text_area :update %></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="row"><%= f.submit %></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Controller

```
  def edit
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lead.update_attributes(params[:lead])
        if @lead.save
          flash[:notice] = "Lead was successfully updated."
        end
        format.html { render action: "edit"  }

        #format.html { redirect_to @lead, notice: 'Lead was successfully updated.' }
        #format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this By doing this:

```
  def enter_notes
    time = Chronic.parse('now').strftime('%m-%d-%Y %l:%M %p')
    oldnotes = @lead.notes
    params[:lead][:notes] = "#{time} #{params[:lead][:note1]} \n\n#{oldnotes}"
    params[:lead].delete(:note1)
  end

  def update
    @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
    enter_notes
    if @lead.update_attributes(params[:lead])
      flash[:notice] = "Lead was successfully updated."
      if @lead.updated?
        redirect_to edit_lead_path(@leads[@index])
      else
        render action: "edit"
      end
    else
       render action: "edit"
    end

  end
```